# Partial file encryption with AES

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-optimization, aes

Task is to encrypt part of the file using aes encryption algorithm. I did

```
public static byte[] AES_(int len, byte[] passwordBytes, byte[] saltBytes, FileStream fSin)
{

    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
    byte[] encryptedBytesAndIV = null;

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 100);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = generateIV();

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
                int read,read2=0;


                while (read2 < len)
                {
                    read = fSin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    read2 += read;
                }
                cs.Close();


            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            encryptedBytesAndIV = new byte[encryptedBytes.Length + AES.IV.Length];
            AES.IV.CopyTo(encryptedBytesAndIV, 0);
            encryptedBytes.CopyTo(encryptedBytesAndIV, IV_LENGTH);
        }
    }

    return encryptedBytesAndIV;
}
private static byte[] generateIV()
{
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        byte[] nonce = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
        rng.GetBytes(nonce);
        return nonce;
    }
}
```

call function

```
  FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
len = Convert.ToInt32(fsIn.Length) / 3;
 var resultb = AES_(len, passwordBytes, saltBytes, fsIn);


    fsIn.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fsIn.Write(resultb, 0, resultb.Length);

    fsIn.Seek(fsIn.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    fsIn.Write(saltBytes, 0, saltBytes.Length);
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fsIn))
{
    writer.Seek(Convert.ToInt32(fsIn.Length), SeekOrigin.Begin);
    writer.Write(resultb.Length);

}
```

The problem is that when a large file consumes a lot of memory and the computer freezes.Is it possible to alter this code so that the memory consumption of the PC was the minimum ?

As I understand it, that is the memory write bytes to the MemoryStream, but how different ? I need to overwrite the bytes in the same file if the same record byte immediately into a new file, it will have to write all the remaining bytes, and it is a waste of time and also memory

Comment: _a large file consumes a lot of memory_ a lot of data requries a lot of memory and since you are not just encrpting the file with a stream but also return the encrypted version from the method you need to load it completely into memory.

Comment: @t3chb0t it turns out that nothing can be done ?

Comment: I believe that it could be possible but you don't provide enough code. Currently you read a part from a file, encrypt it and read into memory... then I guess you use this buffer to write it into a new file. I'm pretty sure this could be done _fluently_ so that you read from a file, then encrypt a few bytes then write the rest into the new file without storing too much data in memory. But the part where you read, encrypt, write is missing. It's not (only) the encryption that needs optimizing but rather the whole process.

Comment: @t3chb0t thank you, you gave a good idea. You are so mean
[link](https://pastebin.com/Z4BF4eYb)

Comment: Three minor notes: 1. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implements `IDisposable` and therefore should be wrapped in a `using` construct. 2. `.CreateEncryptor()` creates an `IDisposable` resource. It should be pulled out and wrapped in a `using` construct. 3. `cs.Close();` isn't needed as the `using` scope will close and dispose it immediately thereafter.